# Track how many times method has been called with Sinon/Mocha

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing a test using Mocha/Sinon to ensure that an `async tryAtMost` function I've created is calling a Promise and only retrying that promise `X` amount of times.

My `tryAtMost` function looks like:

```
  async tryAtMost(options, promise, maxRetries, retryInterval = 0) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        const res = await promise(options);
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          return resolve(res);
        } else {
          if (maxRetries > 0) {
            setTimeout(async () => {
              return await this.tryAtMost(options, promise, maxRetries - 1, retryInterval);
            }, retryInterval);
          } else {
            return reject('Ran out of retries, failing.');
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
    });
  }
```

My Mocha test creates a stub for my `promise` library, and I can force it to return whatever status code I want. However, I want my test to be able to verify that `tryAtMost` is only invoked `maxRetries + 1` amount of times. If someone more familiar with Mocha/Sinon could help me figure out how to do this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 9):

[Sinon spies](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/) solved this perfectly for me. I made a spy of my method to wrap it, and all I had to do was check `tryAtMostSpy.callCount`. The docs made it very easy :)